# What is the convention for dealing with unanswered questions where suggestions can no longer be tested?

Tags: discussion, bounties

I've ended up in a situation where I was experiencing a serious bug on my PC. [I posted a question on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/361341/ie9-development-tools-giving-unable-to-attach-to-the-process-error) in an attempt to rectify it.

However, no solution was found, and since I needed it resolving I was forced to rebuild my PC to make it behave properly.

The question is still open with a bounty, but I am no longer able to test the suggestions people are giving me.

What is the correct thing for me to do in this situation? Should I close the question or accept the best of the answers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only real option seems to be not to accept an answer and leave the top answer in the hands of the upvoters.

It seems appropriate in a way. They did not solve your specific problem, since the problem expired. An accept should mean that the one who posted the question was helped by that answer.

Comment: Also, indicating the fact that you are no longer looking for an answer, through a comment.

Comment: @Kris. Like this?- http://superuser.com/questions/361341/ie9-development-tools-giving-unable-to-attach-to-the-process-error

Answer (score 4):

Don't close the question -- someone else might know the exact answer and save future troubleshooters hours of pain with a ready answer.

As for the bounty, that's unfortunate; if you think one of the answerers went above the call of duty, feel free to award it yourself. Otherwise The System will award the bounty to whoever the votes dictate, which is a nice enough outcome.

Don't bother accepting any answers though. It might only provide false information to future visitors.

Comment: What the OP is saying is that he cannot verify if the answer is correct.

Comment: That's why I suggest _not_ accepting answers.

Comment: I was referring to "someone else might know the exact answer"; if the OP is not able to verify the given answer, who is able to say which one is the exact answer?

Comment: A hypothesized future reader might find the question describes their problem and an answer exactly fixes it -- and garners another upvote. The site is for more than just the original questioners. :)

Comment: That doesn't mean that a question that is too generic to be answered, as as this seems to be the case, can ever be answered. Somebody could have resolved the same problem doing X, and somebody else could have resolved the problem doing Y. For the future readers, knowing that A people resolved it doing X, and B people resolved it doing Y is not helpful, as they could need to do Z, to resolve their problem.

Comment: @kiamlaluno If they find out answer Z is also a good solution, ideally they'd post answer Z as a third answer. That's how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: @Aberrant I find easier to close the question. Every user could add their own answer, but to the future readers none of the answers is probably useful, as there isn't a way to say which one works better. If there is an accepted answer, you could suppose that is the one that works better, but in this case it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

To make a summary, the question got three answers, but what suggested in those answers didn't help resolving the reported issue.

The question cannot be close because there is a pending bounty that you offered. Once the bounty is over the question can be closed.
Basing on the comment left from arrymc, I would think the question could be closed as "too localized"; it could be also closed as "not a real question" as the description given for that closing reason says, "This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

> Something is wrong, and is probably related to permissions, but it is hard to guess what has changed on your computer.

As you offered a bounty, you could flag the question for moderation attention (selecting, "it needs ♦ moderator attention," and then "other"), and explain that the question is not anymore relevant for you, it's probably of none interest for other users too, and that you would like to have back the reputation you put for the bounty.
Moderators can return the reputation offered for a bounty; if you explain exactly your situation, and moderators agree with you, they can given you back your reputation, and close the question.

If this fails, then you can always vote to close your question, once the bounty is over.

Between the two, the first is probably better, as nobody would get the bounty for an answer that really didn't resolve the issue reported in the question. (At least, that is what I get from the comments you left for each answer.)